# How do Saas companies support different domains with different databases

Tags: saas, country, bitrix

I see several SaaS companies, such as bitrix have different top level domains by country ex:
bitrix.de for germany
bitrix.in for india etc.

A lot of times this is required because of legal requirements that the data generated in Germany should stay within the EU/German data center, and vice versa same for India.

**My queries**

1. To achieve the above, there would be 1 database + 1 App Server in India, and a similar 1 database + App server for Germany also?
2. What should happen if a user created an account on bitrix.in ie in the Indian database, and then he goes and tries to accidentally log in to bitrix.com, should such a login go through or should I tell the user that he is on the wrong site?

Tx

Comment: and why couldn't the database be the same for every country? Even if there were many because they had to be distributed around the world, the data would still be shared between all of them

Comment: If the database is same for all countries, then the legal requirement of ensuring EU data stays in EU, Singapore Data stays in Singapore etc. cannot be met.
If they are in different databases, then how do you sync data across databases where both are being written to?

Comment: if you request your data from another country, it will take you a little longer to receive the response, because the database you're trying to access doesn't have your data. It's not like it's shared for no reason, it is only when you want it to. And if data about you is being written or requested from two different places at the same time, then there's some security problem there, because you can't be in two places at the same time, can you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a central database for storing meta data - accounts, logins, etc. This could be common/shared across all countries/domains or it could be separate in each database but replicated at a central meta database.

Now when someone logs in, after authentication (using the central meta database) you can redirect them to the appropriate domain.

In such a configuration when creating a new user you will have to ensure that the user is unique across all domains/databases.